# Where are the other 7 Bijuus after the Shinobi World War?

Tags: naruto, naruto-gaiden

After the Shinobi World War, only Naruto & Killer Bee become a Jinchuuriki.

Where are the other 7 Bijuus after the Shinobi World War?

Answer (score 3):

We don't know the exact location of the bijuus, but they have returned to their homes!

**In the chapter #692:**

> [image]